# How to convert flat file into nested JSON using cs class

Tags: c#, json

I have created a JSON string below from a data table and generated classes from the desired nested output.   I need help with the c sharp code behind to convert the string to a nested object.  Do I need to create a bespoke serialiser for this?  Is there a better method?

```
string = [{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase1","id" :1001, "type": "glove"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase1","id" :1002, "type": "shoe"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase1","id" :1003, "type": "sock"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase2","id" :1005, "type": "large"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase2","id" :1006, "type": "medium"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase2","id" :1007, "type": "small"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase3","id" :1008, "type": "ladies"},
{"name":"example1", "priority" : "high", "PHASE": "phase3","id" :1009, "type": "gents"}];



desired_output = {
"NAME": "example1",
"PRIORITY" : "high",
"PHASE":
          {
            "phase1":
                      [
                       { "id": "1001", "type": "glove" },
               { "id": "1002", "type": "shoe" },
               { "id": "1003", "type": "sock",

"ph2":
           {
              "phase2" :
                      [
                       { "id": "1005", "type": "large" },
               { "id": "1006", "type": "medium" },
               { "id": "1007", "type": "small", 
"ph3":
           {
             "phase3": 
                        [
                       { "id": "1008", "type": "ladies" },
               { "id": "1009", "type": "gents" }

]}
}
]}
}
]
}
}


public class Phase3
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Ph3
{
    public List<Phase3> phase3 { get; set; }
}

public class Phase2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Ph3 ph3 { get; set; }
}

public class Ph2
{
    public List<Phase2> phase2 { get; set; }
}

public class Phase1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Ph2 ph2 { get; set; }
}

public class PHASE
{
    public List<Phase1> phase1 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRIORITY { get; set; }
    public PHASE PHASE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need that the ph are nested or you want as separate object (hierarchally you wqant ph1>ph2>ph3>ph4 or the ph on the same level?)

Comment: Hi, I'd like it with hierarchy; ph1>ph2>ph3>ph4.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse your json into a `List<RootObject1>` where the `RootObject1` is defined as:

```
public class RootObject1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string PHASE { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

You can easly done this task using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)` inside `JSON.Net`.
Once you have the List you can `GroupBy` by PHASE to group the list by PHASE. The code it's something like this:

```
var groups = myList.GroupBy(x => x.PHASE);
```

Now that you have groups(defined as `IENumerable<IGrouping<string,RootObject1>>`) you need a foreach to go in each group and fill the proper class (and order by type iof I'm not wrong).
Once you have finished the foreach cycle serialize your RootObject and you will get the json formatted as you want.
Just an hint: the `PhaseN` should be `assays` otherwise you will not get the correct result.

Comment: please can you provide more help on how to group and fill classes?